# R function for Power Curves

Tags: r

When power curves give you the bends,
This R function is your friend. 
If it’s normality you want, 
Or linearity to flaunt, 
This woodsy flavor is not base 10.

(hint: the answer doesn’t rhyme) and we’ll get back to you shortly.

The second part of the riddle indicates the "ln" function but since it's "woodsy", I'm leaning towards "naturallog" as part of the name, though I'm open to the idea that it could be something else.

I am however, at a loss for the R function associate with helping out with Power curves. There seem to be a number of functions that can be used for (statistical) Power curves.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

The answer is `log`. From the help `?log`:

log computes logarithms, by default natural logarithms, log10 computes common (i.e., base 10) logarithms, and log2 computes binary (i.e., base 2) logarithms. The general form log(x, base) computes logarithms with base base.

So the riddle is pointing to the difference between `log` and `log10`